# How to export query result on raster table in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, query

I did success query on a raster table in PostGIS (raster data clipped by a vector polygon), now I want to view the query result in QGIS. But how to export the query result to another table. In vector data, it's simple, just `"CREATE TABLE schema.someTable AS  (...sql in here...);`

How about raster data? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Alien,

That would work for raster as well.  In addition, you'll probably want to call the http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_AddRasterConstraints.html

```
SELECT AddRasterConstraints('yournewtable'::name, 'rast'::name);
```

That will ensure all relevant info is properly exposed in raster_columns view.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use INTO:

```
SELECT ...
INTO schema.table
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-selectinto.html